# What's the reason of duplicate unique index in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I got the task of adapt a very old MySQL database to use its data on another program and I found some very large tables (thousands of rows) with this kind of structure:

```
CREATE TABLE `foo` (
    `Id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `Name` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`Id`),
    UNIQUE KEY `foo_Name_Idx` (`Name`),
    UNIQUE KEY `Name` (`Name`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

What's the reason of these apparently duplicate unique index? Perfomance? Automated table creation error?

Comment: Maybe a database designer that is not so good in database design, or that the column name had a FK relation to another table as the end `_Idx`, usually is generated by mysql when creating a FK. In any case, this has no logical explanation but maybe a simple mistake.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no benefit to redundant indexes like that. MySQL allows you to create them if you specify different names for them, but they should be avoided.

If you want to find all of the redundant indexes in your database I recommend that you use one of these tools:

- If you want to use the shell, use [pt-duplicate-key-checker](http://www.percona.com/doc/percona-toolkit/2.2/pt-duplicate-key-checker.html) from [Percona Toolkit](http://www.percona.com/doc/percona-toolkit/2.2/)

Once installed you can run it at the command line like this:

```
pt-duplicate-key-checker
```

- If you want to use the MySQL CLI, use [redundant_keys](http://common-schema.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/common_schema/doc/html/redundant_keys.html) from [common_schema](http://code.google.com/p/common-schema/)

Once installed you can query it like this:

```
SELECT * FROM common_schema.redundant_keys\G
```

Comment: I installed common_schema (very nice, by the way!) and the redundant_keys command returned all tables with these keys I mentioned on my question. It means that I could save a lot of space, as the tables are large, dropping the duplicated keys, right?

Comment: Yes, dropping the redundant indexes will save a lot of disk space. We aware that the table will be locked while you drop the index, and it will take some time on a large table, so don't do it while the database is being actively used.

Comment: Also just to be safe you may want to check your code base to make sure there are no index hints referencing any of the indexes you plan to drop by name.

Comment: Thanks for the advices! I'm working on a local copy and adapting it to use on new system. The old code will be discontinued. As you said, dropping these redundant indexes saved a lot of space. Thanks!